# Recognise text (both numbers and characters) from image

Tags: python, opencv, keras, conv-neural-network, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to recognise text from image. One of the dataset that contains training  data for both is Emnist. The documentation is as follows [EMNIST documentation](https://www.nist.gov/node/1298471/emnist-dataset). I am training a neural network to do the job. The code is as follows

```py
from emnist import extract_training_samples
x_train,y_train = extract_training_samples('balanced')

from emnist import extract_test_samples
x_test,y_test = extract_test_samples('balanced')

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 47
epochs = 6

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('OCR.h5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=callbacks_list)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

However, when this model is used to predict alphabets by means of findContour method in opencv by creating bounding boxes,it  fails to do the job. For example this sample image

[image: Sample Image]

It can only predict numbers. Kindly suggest me alternative training dataset or please suggest me what can i do to convert this kind of image into text.

Comment: try microsoft OCR. thats pre trained online model for it. It serve as baseline performance.  if that can not do it for your data. then high chance no matter what you do,  you can make it work .   try this code first. https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR.  If can not work, then you change to change a task

Comment: Sigh. I’m sure I made this comment a few hours ago and I assume it was deleted by a mysterious moderator who doesn’t bother to tell me what they think is wrong with my comment and just deleted it. This is what I said which AFAIK isn’t rude or offensive: IMO the quality of your image is so poor that it will be a surprise if you are able to recover anything from it. OCR is very much a Garbage In Garbage Out sort of thing.

Comment: And to the moderator who deleted my comment: what was wrong with it?